Close attic ducts during the winter? (baseboard heat)
Background:
We have natural gas forced hydroponic as our primary heating source in a 2 story colonial in New England. Last year we had a ducted heat pump installed with R-8 insulated ducts in the attic and the basement. It's cheaper to use the boiler in the colder months so I plan on switching over and turning the heat pump off.
Question: My priority is to avoid mold in the ducts and I'm less concerned about potential cost savings from either leaving the register open/closed. Should I close the registers or leave them open?

leave then OPEN, the air in the ducts is not from outside, it is just circulated inside

Open or closed the ducts won't grow mold unless they have a source of water inside.  If there is no leak causing water infiltration or very high humidity, there won't be mold.

If you have R-8 ducts exposed in a New England attic (as opposed to run along the ceiling and buried in lots of additional insulation) you will almost certainly get condensation in the cold ducts. R-8 is not even 1/5 the recommended attic insulation here. Warm, moist house air will get into them and cool on exposure to cold attic air.
